# LINQPad doesn't show all tables

Tags: linqpad

LINQPad doesn't show all tables. 
I can see the tables in Connection Explorer in Visual Studio, but not in LINQPad.
I can however query successfully in LINQPad the other tables I can see.

Comment: note: if table belongs to not dbo schema, it might be show lower under schema name